# All access attempts share the same IP Address Django-Axes

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue where all access logs/attempts recorded to the server via the Django-axes module are under the same IP address. These two logs seen below were made under two different IP addresses, yet they are recorded as if they are the same. Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Documentation if necessary: https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

[image: Access Logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some kind of proxy/load balancer before your actual server and you do not set [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header so django-axes cannot catch actual IP

`10.0.0.0/8` is IP range meant to be used for private networks

Comment: Thank you, most likely a problem with my host. I'll look into it.

Comment: it could be your ngnix/apache configuration